# complex django or SQL query

Tags: sql, django

A record can have status 'renewal_required'. If it enters this status, and the applicant indeed renews, a copy is generated, which enters status 'in_process' (But an application can have status 'in_process' for other reasons too).

Now I need to get all records that have renewal_required status, BUT, if a copy exists in status 'in_process' for a given applicant, I shall only show that one...the key is the applicant_id, being the same for copied records.

```
| id | status               | applicant_id |
| 1  |    renewal_required  |       2      |
| 2  |    in_process        |       3      |  
| 3  |    renewal_required  |       4      |
| 4  |    in_process        |       4      |
```

in the above example, records with id 1 and 4 would be returned...

Can this be done? Thanks for *any* suggestion (DB-redesign excluded, even if the design looks ridiculous - can't do anything about it right now)

Solution needs to be for django but if a SQL solution is being proposed I will happily accept it and adapt/execute directly

Comment: The design is the problem here unfortunately - you have a status flag (here being "in_process") can mean two different things depending on the _context_, and you have no means to differentiate the context. So, the _real_ solution is to create another status code which is for "renewal_processing" or similar.

Comment: What is the database being used?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.applicant_id,COALESCE(b.status,a.status) status from 
(select applicant_id,status from yourtable where status='renewal_required') a
left join 
(select applicant_id,status from yourtable where status='in_process')  b 
on a.applicant_id = b.applicant_id;
```

check the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/52cfc/3)

Comment: This returns an error regarding the ifnull function: 
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Using postgres btw

Comment: which DBMS are you using? check the demo for mysql.

Comment: as I put in my first comment, using postgresql

Comment: oh! I'm sorry I didn't see that while skimming. ok then use coalesce instead

Comment: thanks to you too, the query runs now but returns 0 elements. :) Looking to see if I can find another solution altogether not offloading all complexity to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Here, a possible solution

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id) as max_id, t1.status, t1.applicant_id
  FROM t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(status) as status, applicant_id
      FROM t1
      WHERE status in ('renewal_required', 'in_process')
      GROUP by applicant_id ) tmp
    ON t1.status = tmp.status 
      AND t1.applicant_id = tmp.applicant_id
  GROUP BY t1.status, t1.applicant_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa490/3)

**EDIT:** Rethought it, now this one won't work if there are more statuses than just these two, because of `SELECT MIN(status)`. Could you comment on that?

**EDIT2:** Might be like this it will. added `WHERE status in ('renewal_required', 'in_process')`

Comment: This looks like very close but returns only two records in total, having the same applicant_id, different id but both 'in_process' - which from data sanity point of view doesn't look like ok either...

Comment: In fact there are 1323 records with 'in_process' status and 206 with 'requires_renewal'. There should be only a few of copies due to the issue described in the problem description, so the result set should be bigger

Comment: Could you clarify the logic a bit, is it possible to have two records with status 'request_renewal' and the same applicant_id at a time in your table?

Comment: I have two records with same applicant_id and status 'in_process'; there should be only one in status 'request_renewal' but I can't confirm, taking over this project from someone else.

Comment: Can you tell me then how many statuses are there all in all. Only two - 'renewal' and 'in process' ?

Comment: thanks for your efforts man, now I get results in 'in_process' status only, which isn't right either. I am trying to find a different approach which doesn't offload all complexity to the DB.

Comment: @fablife that should be okay, are you sure you are not getting only 'in_process' ones because all the 'renewal_required' ones are overlapped? In sql fiddle there it works just fine... Or might be there are more complexities which you haven't told us about yet?

Comment: No, I just checked, the first three results are in_process only. It's possible there are more complexities of which I am myself even not yet aware of! I just took over this project.